# force QListWidget signal to emit in pyside

Tags: python, pyside

How can I force any of the following signals to emit from within a function which is fired from a button push?

```
def currentItemChanged (current, previous)
def currentRowChanged (currentRow)
def currentTextChanged (currentText)
def itemActivated (item)
def itemChanged (item)
def itemClicked (item)
def itemDoubleClicked (item)
def itemEntered (item)
def itemPressed (item)
def itemSelectionChanged ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emit the signals yourself. Assuming `self` is an instance of a `QListWidget`:

```
self.itemActivated.emit(myItem)
self.currentTextChanged.emit("some new text")
...
```